# Marketo Modules — Deleting Elements

Tags: email-templates, marketo

I'm trying to figure out if an element can be completely deleted within a module. Lets say I have editable text within a module — I can clear the text from within the element, but I can't outright delete that element so it's space is removed from the module and content below, moves up to fill it's place.

The image below illustrates what I'm trying to do.[image]

Is there a way to achieve the result in the 3rd image? Perhaps by using snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the content from a rich-text element won't completely collapse the section, however, if you write an HTML comment within the rich-text element it will collapse the section completely.

<!-- -->

Comment: hey thanks a lot, it worked by putting the mktoText class and associated attributes on the <tr> that holds the <td> with the content inside. if you keep the class on the <td> and try to comment the content inside of it out, it will leave the padding.

is there a consequence for putting that class on a <tr> though?